# How to check that header is not empty?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, exception

I have a header in my endpoint with a type of `UUID`. How can I verify that it's not empty (`--header 'My-Header;' \` in curl) and throw an exception (I'm going to use `@ExceptionHandler`) in case if it is empty?

```java
@RequestHeader(value = "My-Header") final UUID myHeader
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned

> and throw an exception (I'm going to use @ExceptionHandler)

leave it as it is in your controller method `@RequestHeader(value = "My-Header") final UUID myHeader`

`required` attribute of this annotation defaults to true!

And according to the documentation, in absense a `MissingRequestHeaderException` exception would be thrown.

Then you can handle this exception

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MissingRequestHeaderException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleMissingHeaderException(MissingRequestHeaderException e) {
        return return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(String.format("%s header is missing from the request", e.getHeaderName()));
    }
}
```

This way you can handle missing headers from other controller methods as well.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please share a link to the documentation?

Comment: @AndreiKulik 
required -> Defaults to true, leading to an exception being thrown if the header is missing in the request. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html

Comment: Hmm ... I see a strange thing in the work of this implementation. After the called endpoint (header is empty), my service is calling as well! I've expected to get `MissingRequestHeaderException` and stop working.

Comment: It seem like there is an issue for that in spring boot https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23939 What you can do is you can check in your controller if UUID is null and then manually throw the same exception

Answer (score 2):

```
    @GetMapping("/nonRequiredHeader")
public ResponseEntity<String> evaluateNonRequiredHeader(
  @RequestHeader(value = "optional-header", required = false) String optionalHeader) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(String.format(
      "Was the optional header present? %s!",
        (optionalHeader == null ? "No" : "Yes")),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Please follow this : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers
for more info

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I should have said this before, I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this. For example with the help of annotations.

Comment: Oh. Probably I've got your point. If `optionalHeader` is empty, then it will be null because `required = false`.

Comment: The 'required' element of @RequestHeader
This element defines whether the header is required. The default is true. That means the status code 400 will be returned if the header is missing in the request. We can switch this to false if we prefer a null value if the header is not present in the request.